# Python | Addition of numpy arrays with different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of the shapes (4, 1) and (4,) respectively. I want to add these two arrays the conventional way to get an array with four elements. For example,

```
A = np.array([[3],[5],[4],[2]])
B = np.array([3,5,4,2])
```

I want C= A+B to be np.array([6,10,8,4]) (preferably of the shape (4,). But when, I add these two arrays (A and B), I get a 4*4 matrix.

```
print A+B
[[  6.   8.   7.   5.]
 [  8.  10.   9.   7.]
 [  7.   9.   8.   6.]
 [  5.   7.   6.   4.]]
```

What am I missing and how can I achieve the functionality that I am aiming for?

Comment: .. `A[:,0] + B`?

Comment: `A.ravel() + B` or `A.squeeze() + B` or `A.reshape(-1, ) + B` or what Divakar said.

Comment: Do you want a (4,) or (4,1) shape?

Comment: @hpaulj I want (4,) shape. I changed the typo in my question. Thanks for pointing this out. :)